# Powershell script with multiple msiexec calls

Tags: windows, script, powershell

---

I am having problem with multiple msiexec calls in my PS Script

```
msiexec /package $msi1 /l*v $logfolder\log1.log /qn
msiexec /x $msi2 /l*v $logfolder\log2.log /qn
msiexec /i $msi3 /l*v $logfolder\log3.log /qn
```

The problem is that that they are launched all together instead of waiting for the previous to finish, I don't have the same problem with a bat script. There is a solution to wait few minutes, but its not the best option. Can you suggest something better ?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I am trying to deploy 2 browsers, but in the end nothing happens, because they all run together at once.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions provided here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741490/how-to-tell-powershell-to-wait-for-each-command-to-end-before-starting-the-next

Comment: this actually works, thank you Jsanchez, this is brilliant thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is already answered on SO to the OP's satisfaction  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741490/how-to-tell-powershell-to-wait-for-each-command-to-end-before-starting-the-next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of "[How to tell PowerShell to wait for each command to end before starting the next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741490/how-to-tell-powershell-to-wait-for-each-command-to-end-before-starting-the-next)" where Keith Hill has provided a few solutions.